# Graceful shutdown of a process

Tags: haskell

I want to close a store connection (adding a function like `close eventStoreConnection`) when the process is about to shutdown :

```
main = do
     eventStoreConnection <- EventStore.connect EventStore.defaultSettings (EventStore.Static "127.0.0.1" 1113)
     scotty 3000 $ do
       get  "/health/liveness" $ do html "OK"
       post "/introduceIdea" $ do
          command <- jsonData
          liftIO $ persist eventStoreConnection command
          html "OK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bracket](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket).  Like:

```
let connect = EventStore.connect EventStore.defaultSettings (EventStore.Static "127.0.0.1" 1113))
bracket connect close $ \eventStoreConnection ->
    scotty 3000 $ ...
```